# Domain Name Suggestions?

Tags: discussion, top-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/553/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name rpg.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/553/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Domain name suggestions? Please only put one domain name per answer, so we can vote on them.

**Can you please indicate if your suggestion is available or taken.** Check [**here**](http://whois.net).

Comment: discussing domain names will most likely end with some annoying person buying the agreed one just to be a jerk. I hope it doesn't happen, but I feel it would be better the brainstorming is done through a different mean with selected people (chosen by the diamond users)

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but should this be CW?

Comment: Can the suggestions for domains that are already taken be removed from the listing?

Comment: I note there isn't 'one suggestion per answer' in the question. Should there be?

Comment: @RMorrisey why remove names already taken?  There's a number of domains that are being squatted, so if it fits our needs better it may be possible to still get it.  Take a look at the post about domain names: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/

Comment: Thanks, disregard my previous comment

Comment: We have to have some cheesy catchphrase like "Putting the Quest in Question"

Comment: I think the name should sound useful and practical as a source of information first, funny or in-joke-laden second. For that, the domain name should be self-explanatory or nearly so. Something like askroleplayers.com (which I've suggested).

Comment: Extra points for being "like" the normal SE names (two words, first starting with an S) and not bizarrely crypto-fantastical

Comment: So when does this question end?  When the beta is over?

Comment: @LeguRi: what about "Accepting the Quest of your Question!"?

Comment: @yhw42 - The possibilities are endless!! :D

Comment: @MadMaxJr - It looks like some initiative has been taken based on this thread: [askthetable.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/askthetable.com) and [stackofdice.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/stackofdice.com) have both been purchased by Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc. Perhaps a mod should close this and open a tie-breaker question?

Comment: @C. Ross @Bryant - Looks like there will be no domain name after all: see [Public Service Announcement: ongoing, offsite discussion about Area51 graduates' branding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area51-graduates) Anyone else find it a little sketch that that decision was made after buying the domains we voted on?

Answer (score 11):

(split from earlier, by request. Untaken (at time of original posting))

askthetable.com

Comment: Site is currently parked by GoDaddy.com

Comment: It's registered to Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc. and was registered on 03-Sept-2010. :)

Answer (score 11):

StackOfDice.com

Edit:
Currently parked by GoDaddy.com on behalf of Stack Overflow

Comment: MadMAxJr recommended using a stack of dice as a play off the stack overflow logo.  This would go well with that.  I like the idea of using a visual and verbal pun used together.

http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108/site-logo-design

Answer (score 5):

stackthedice.com

Available. Has a double-entendre, playing on "stack exchange" and on "stacking the deck" in favour of a better game. Though, I think a better variation on that double-entendre can probably be done. Someone do it!

Answer (score 3):

criticalfailure.com ?

Taken.

Comment: That's taken, alas.

Comment: Although you know, critical-failure.net is not taken, and I like the general idea a lot.

Comment: Perhaps rollforcriticalfailure.com ?

Answer (score 3):

knowledgecheck.com

Taken, but appears to be unused.

Answer (score 3):

Saving Throw (savingthrow.com).  Pleasingly like "Stack Overflow" etc.  Taken but being used by a 17 year old on his blog, I imagine the SE guys could bribe him easily :-)

Comment: I love this one, and I'm upvoting it, and I claim it's generic because, um... Tunnels and Trolls uses saving throws as well. So the first two fantasy RPGs use the term. Yep.

Comment: +1, very nice. Although the joke is probably lost on any non-d20 based/related systems (TBE, WoD, SR, ...)

Answer (score 2):

Another

```
LandOfDice.com
```

Comment: I like this one.  My reservation, though, is that overlooks diceless systems.

Answer (score 2):

ruleslawyer.com

Answer (score 2):

savevsconfusion.com

Answer (score 2):

askroleplayers.com (available)

Answer (score 2):

legendslore.com

Registered by a domain reseller; for sale.

Answer (score 1):

criticalmiss.com

Taken.

Comment: Whoops, I misread. This is taken.

Answer (score 1):

www.gamemastered.com

Comment: +1 I just posted that as well before reading all the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

(split from earlier, by request)
deargamemaster.com

Answer (score 1):

## questoverload.com

(available)

You didn't sign up to fight yet another random encounter! There are worlds to save!

Comment: I originally proposed this for Gaming, but it likely is a better fit here.

Comment: Heh when I read this I thought "this would be a better fit for gaming."  "Quest" tends to be used in the context of CRPGs/MMOs not tabletop in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

askrpgers.com (available)

Answer (score 0):

[Bulk suggestions; they're all available as individual answers now.]

Comment: askthetable.com is one of the better ones I've seen so far

Comment: What about just take20.com?

Comment: I think take 20 is even more D20 system centric than "Natural 1"

Comment: askthetable has a nice ring.

Comment: @todiasopdenbrouw: Posting these as one, big answer doesn't allow anyone to vote. Please post separately and delete this. Thanks.

Comment: Can this answer be split into separate answers? I'd like to vote up some and vote down others separately.

Comment: @Robert + @Richard: split into seperate answers. I will delete this answer once I see action on the new split ones.

Comment: Tobias hasn't been around for a few days - taking the liberty to edit this down to avoid confusion.

Comment: That's fine Bryant.

Answer (score 0):

DiceySubjects.com?

Answer (score 0):

howweroll.com - Short form of "Is This How We Roll?" or "This Is How We Roll", depending on implication.

Taken.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a few suggestions floating around in comments...

http://www.rollforcriticalfailure.com

Comment: Seems a bit long to me

Answer (score 0):

Another

```
 MysticScroll.com
```

Answer (score 0):

(split from earlier, by request)
deardungeonmaster.com

Answer (score 0):

(split from earlier, by request)

sayyesorrollthedice.com

Comment: Too indie-games specific.

Answer (score 0):

allworkisplay.com

Answer (score 0):

rollyourattack.com (or roleyourattack.com)

Answer (score 0):

rollinginitiative.com

Answer (score 0):

grabyourdice.com

Answer (score 0):

Player Character

(registered but not in use; .net variants available)

Answer (score -1):

www.rocksfall.com

Taken.

Comment: And also taken. :)

Comment: r0xf4llz.com is available :)

Comment: Hahaha :D joking aside, though, `r0xf4llz` distances the site from its table-top focus, methinks.

Answer (score -1):

rpgTableTopGames.com

Answer (score -1):

<strike>TotalPartyKill.info</strike>

Total-Party-Kill.com

Comment: Jeff said only .com.  You could always buy it and do a redirect though...

Comment: @C.Ross Thanks! I didn't know about that requirement. Changed my answer to use a .com

Comment: There is already a totalpartykill.com; not technically taken, but it seems redundant.

Answer (score -1):

Natural_One.com

Comment: I'm not sold on the underscore, but naturalone.com suggests something to with naturism... :)

Comment: Natural 1 is kind of D20 specific, no?

Comment: Yes it is but D&D is by far the most popular RPG out there.

Comment: ... and I don't think domain names can contain underscores.

Comment: what about `natural1.com`.  It's currently taken, but doesn't appear to be used and is set to expire October 18 this year.

Comment: Instead of the suggested, try Natural-One.com  I'm also pretty sure underscores don't work in domain names.

Answer (score -1):

kind of mundane but therpgexchange sounds good to me. But I vote for the naturalone idea as well it fits with parent site Stack Overflow. Critical Failure is also good and less D&Dish in it's focus.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt it will be catchy, but after for whatever reason [Knights of the Dinner Table](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5g337Imvlc#t=1m22s) popped in my head:

TheDiceTauntMeWithLowRolls.com

Answer (score -1):

Another classic RPG joke:

**fearthegazebo.com**

Comment: Like ten years ago, I emailed the guy who made the original gazebo post, and he was pretty protective of the rights to the story.

Answer (score -1):

**rollingroles.com**

Comment: +1 - I like the idea of a word play between role and roll. Perhaps something like `rollplaying.com` or `rollandplay.com`

Answer (score -1):

MadMaxJr [kind of proposed](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/what-should-our-faq-contain/172#172) "YeOldeSwordExchange.com". I think it's too long. But we can work from here.
The main issue is that they are fantasy oriented domain names. What about Cyberpunk RPGs ? the domain name should be method agnostic and setting agnostic. mhmm....

What about a completely disconnected name, such as one of a place or similar:

```
Arcaria, Serinai, Mikeides, Morlekur, Samyria
```

Should we try mindmapping concepts ? When do we have to deliver the domain name proposal ?

I splitted names so you can vote them independently.

Comment: Please post your suggestions as separate answers so people can vote. Thanks.

Comment: I like `landofdice.vom` :D Make it a separate answer and I'm bound to up-vote.

Comment: @Richard @Robert done.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to have a few suggestions floating around in comments...

http://www.rollandplay.com

Answer (score -1):

Separating answers

```
YeOldeGamer.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Another one

```
YeOldeDie.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Another

```
YeOldeSpell.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Another

```
MistyTaverns.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Another

```
RampartsOfDoom.com
```

Answer (score -1):

(split from earlier, by request)

rpgreplies.com

Answer (score -1):

deadseriousgames.com

Answer (score -1):

deadseriousgamers.com

Answer (score -1):

rpgascendant.com

Answer (score -1):

innmeet.com is one idea

Answer (score -1):

hereistheplan.com

Answer (score -2):

www.IRolledAOne.com

Answer (score -2):

ThePriceofPower

Answer (score -2):

**summonergeeks.com**

From the [Dead Alewives D&D sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Alewives)

Answer (score -3):

**attackingthedarkness.com**

From the [Dead Alewives D&D sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Alewives)

Edit: video rehash of the sketch:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zng5kRle4FA

...now you have no excuse.

Comment: please post suggestions as separate answers so people can vote. Thanks.

Comment: Split into two answers

Comment: I'm going with -1 on this since I've never heard of the reference.

Comment: Added a link to the most commonly-seen version, a CG remake using the original soundtrack

Answer (score -3):

(split from earlier, by request)

canitake20.com

Comment: Too d20 specific