# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, top-7

Hey, let's ask the FAQ question! Now I am going to go be talkative in the answers. One answer per answer, vote up/down depending on whether you think it should be there, yes?

**Update:** I will be editing these into the FAQ soon, so make your suggestions and votes!

Answer (score 10):

Q: What kinds of questions should be marked as community wiki questions?

A: If your question is intended to gather a list of equally relevant answers, and you don't expect one answer to be the most applicable, it should be a community wiki. For example, if you ask for a list of cyberpunk-themed RPGs, that'd be a community wiki. If you ask what would be a good cyberpunk RPG for a game in which posthumanism and uplifting non-human races are major themes, that's probably not a community wiki.

Comment: I believe it is for any question that could have more than one useful answer, not necessarily having one correct answer.  A few of my questions I have asked fall into this.

Comment: Would it make sense to rephrase this somewhat, or perhaps add another Q/A, that explains what things aren't appropriate EVEN as community wiki questions? Some people seem to be using the following algorithm: "Is there one definitive answer? If yes, question, if no, community wiki." But there's more going on there, especially "is it wholly subjective?" and "is it just going to spark the same argument we've all read a thousand times before?"

Answer (score 9):

"What is a Role-Playing Game?"

You know, that blurb that they put in the front of every single RPG core rulebook ever published. I think we should have our own version, for newbies, so they understand what we're about. A link to some more official source wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You think the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_game) top blurb is good enough?

Comment: Not really; it's dry, dense, and needlessly technical. The author spends too much energy trying to cover all of the possibilities. The intro should be short and sweet, and should capture the imagination of visitors, to make them want to look around the site.

Answer (score 9):

What should I not ask here?

- Where to find a game in *your city*.
- Who would like to play in my game?
- Where to buy games.
- In character questions.

Comment: The comment on in character questions got me thinking of 'Ye Olde Swordexchange'.  What is the best way to learn to ride a horse?  The orcs in the foothills keep raiding our village, what would be a good deterent method?  I am a magic user who uses power constructively, how do I convince commoners I am not a witch?  Unrelated, but it got me to chuckle.

Comment: @MadMaxJr : LOL :D that would be a nice domain name. YeOldeSwordExchange.com ... too long maybe :)

Comment: @Stefano, go suggest it!

Comment: She's a witch! burn her!!

Comment: Cribbing from ServerFault's FAQ...

"Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

If you want to talk about the site itself, please don't do it here. Visit our meta-discussion site where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, suggest a feature, or generally discuss how RPG Stack Exchange works."

Comment: If your question is about …

    * Computer RPGs or MMORPGs, ask on gaming.stackexchange.com.
    * RPG or genre related movies, comics, novels, or other media, ask... Somewhere else? 
    * Card games, miniature games, wargames, and boardgames, ask... Somewhere else?

Comment: @mxyzplk Write those into your own answer so I can vote them up!!!

Answer (score 8):

Q: Are trivial questions OK?

A: Yep. Stack Exchange sites are not meant as the second place to go for answers after Google; it's OK to ask questions that can be answered by other means. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions) from our parent site explains more of the reasoning behind this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered! If you want to talk about the site itself, please don't do it here. Visit our meta-discussion site where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, suggest a feature, or generally discuss how RPG Stack Exchange works.

If your question is about…

- Computer RPGs or MMORPGs, ask on gaming.stackexchange.com.
- RPG or genre related movies, comics, novels, or other media, ask... Somewhere else?
- Card games, miniature games, wargames, and boardgames, ask... Somewhere else?

(Up for suggestions on the somewhere elses)

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games is coming along pretty well; covers card games and board games. Out of family, http://www.boardgamegeek.com/ is an obvious choice.

Comment: Since there are not SE sites for those questions, we could direct users to Area51 so they can create a new proposal or participate in an existing one.

Answer (score 7):

**From:** [Should we worry about spoilers?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/should-we-worry-about-spoilers)

This site may contain spoilers. We try to tag questions that are expected to generate spoilers with `[spoiler]`, but you are not guaranteed to see a spoiler warning before reading a spoiler anywhere on the site.

Comment: Suggest:

"This site may contain spoilers. We try to tag questions that are intended to generate spoilers with [spoiler], but you are not guaranteed to see a spoiler warning before reading a spoiler anywhere on the site. "

Comment: fiddle fiddle "are intended to generate" -> "are likely to generate"

Comment: @Bryant Done.  Feel free to just edit it in the future.

Comment: I woulda but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

When is something system agnostic versus system specific. We've seen a bunch of questions where someone made the question without specific system tags but they only make sense in certain games (or even versions of games for D&D).

So really, when to use system specific tags.

Answer (score 3):

The FAQ needs to clairify what the target audience is for the site.

I propose the target be:
"New and experienced RPG players and RPG game masters"

If the comments come up with something better, I'll edit the post to reflect it.

Edit:

The line "This site is not intended for:" should probably be included with a short list under it that includes computer RPG players and potentially larpers if the other questions ever determine if they are or are not part of the intended audience.

Comment: Who does that leave out? Are we discouraging people who want to play RPGs but don't know where to start?

Comment: Wouldn't that qualify them as new?  Or do you have to have a book to count as new?  Hopefully we won't need a seperate stack-definitions to act as a data dictionary for these things. ;)

Comment: Can we specify _tabletop_ RPGs? Or pen and paper?

Comment: Tabletop would rule out LARP.  I am okay with that, as LARP is potentially broad enough to warrant a stack of its own.

Comment: I think it would qualify them as new, yeah. Separately: yes, I think right now LARP would be separate. I notice that nobody's asked any LARP questions. If they do and they gain traction, we'd probably reevaluate.

Comment: And we need to be really explicit about this not being for computer RPGs.  There's many more of them than there are of us, and people googling for RPG are likely to be CRPGers and assume this is a CRPG site.

Comment: Hmm, stack exchange would be very helpful for LARPs. I tend to have more specific "how-ti" questions when writing/developing those. But I agree they are probably a different stack exchange.

Comment: @mxyzplk - my point exactly; I didn't mean to exclude LARPers.

Comment: @mxyzplk I expect us to have a "Miagrate to gaming" button eventually.

Comment: I propose "RPG Stack Exchange is for players and gamemasters of tabletop role-playing games.  If you play Dungeons & Dragons, Shadowrun, World of Darkness, or any of the thousands of other pen-and-paper RPGs, then you're in the right place to ask your question!"  (Just to name the biggest three in terms of name recognition).

Comment: I like that formulation; I would add 'Dogs in the Vineyard' to it just to get one representative story game in there.

Answer (score 2):

Since we now have the spoiler code implemented, I think the FAQ should contain guidelines for how spoilers should be posted and how to properly use the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that just as the FAQ contains guidelines for asking questions, so also should it include guidelines for answering them.  See [this thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/624/197) for discussion on what those guidelines should be.