# How should spoilers be demarcated

Tags: discussion, questions, spoilers

By fairly large margins we've [agreed](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/should-we-worry-about-spoilers) we are a spoiler zone, that its expected and normal. As we've had a little edit thrash today I think we need to better define what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Questions should be demarcated by the spoiler tag. There does not need to be anything more in the body to set them aside.

If you do not want to see spoilers, add the tag to your ignored tags.

Answer (score 1):

If the OP wishes to place a spoiler warning then I have no issues with that. As spoilers are an issue in the various forms of internet discussion we should go with the original poster discretion as to whether they use tags or explicitly state it at the beginning of the question. The more explicit the warning the better the chance that somebody who care about spoilers will understand what is going on.

Comment: OP don't have much rights on SE about that sort of thing. Why should they here?

Comment: @Jeremiah - I don't believe you are correct. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/  In particular, "Do we demand that every user accept every edit? No." and, "Forcing the issue does nobody any favors, generating active hostility and ill will."

Comment: @Jeremiah actually they do by being able to rollback and edit changes. As Pat stated the editing is not a free license to do whatever you think is justified. The OP and other users can edit as well and if it keeps getting switched back then it should be taken as a message that your edits are not warranted. and the post be left alone. There is no hard and fast rule in this regard. In the specific example of the Voldemort post the OP original wording should stand. Fighting over crumbs of bread in editing wars only leads to ill feelings and reduced participation.

Comment: I think in cases like this, where the community may come to agreement on a certain point, then the OP in fact should not retain rights on this decision.  If the community has decided that there are to be no spoilers, or spoiler warnings should be included in a specific fashion, then the OP needs to respect that instead of insisting that the rest of the community honor their perceived rights to post the question/answer "their way".  In the end, "flag for moderator" + a mod who respects the community's wishes, trumps all.

Comment: Except the mods don't respect the community's wishes consistently, at least not in the case that prompted this.