# What are expectations/policy around spoilers?

Tags: discussion, questions, policy, etiquette, spoilers

I have, on a couple occasions noticed either (1) a spoiler box being used incorrectly - that is, it didn't actually hide all the info that was spoiler info. And (2) a spoiler box being used when the information included in the spoiler did not add any pertinent information to the statement the respondent was making.

On the first occasion I dropped the respondent a comment and they fixed it promptly.  On the second occasion I down-voted the answer and left a comment that I down-voted due to what I thought was an unnecessary spoiler.

Is there an expectation that if a spoiler is used it should be pertinent to the answer, and also are there any guidelines on using spoilers? And lastly when a spoiler box is used is the respondent encouraged (by pop up box or some other method) to consider the implications of including a spoiler?

Comment: Related: [Should we worry about spoilers?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/should-we-worry-about-spoilers) (maybe a duplicate, since it's basically the general policy - besides the mention of the no-longer-used [spoiler] tag)

Comment: @V2Blast that post definitely has some good info, though most of the responses were made before the spoiler box feature was available.