# Is this title a spoiler and how would we avoid the spoiler if so?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spoilers, titles

This question: [Is Tiamat's cold breath supposed to be a Dex save?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/206185/is-tiamats-cold-breath-supposed-to-be-a-dex-save?noredirect=1#comment565475_206185) seems to include a spoiler about the weapons of a boss within the title (I haven't finished the adventure including the boss so I don't know the extent of the spoiler). This old meta discusses how to deal with spoilers: [Should we worry about spoilers?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/should-we-worry-about-spoilers/720#720), but doesn't specify how to make a good title to avoid spoilers.

My suggestions for the aforementioned question would be: "Is this boss monster's breath weapon supposed to be a Dex save?", but I am not sure if it is making the question too vague or hard to find for those who need it.

Comment: [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/206523/does-using-the-knock-spell-on-the-front-door-of-icespire-hold-wake-cryovain?noredirect=1#comment566537_206523) gives me similar vibes.

Answer (score 8):

### It's not a spoiler

It is widely known that Tiamat has a stat block. The question if a specific stat block is correct is ok, and should not be a spoiler in itself.

The question does not specify which campaign, and Tiamat is the end boss in about half a dozen published campaigns, and her stat-block is used for her Krynn-Alter-Ego in at least 2 Dragonlance adventures if my memory serves me right.

The specific question in question offers a very specific question that is not campaign-dependent: How does the *Bigby's/arcane hand* spell interact with Tiamat's breath weapons?

If anything, the title is misleading and should be re-worded as "How does [Spell X] interact with Tiamat's breath weapons?"

Comment: That's a good edit of the question, but I would still argue that the title (as previously stated) included two (albeit very minor) spoilers: 1. Tiamat has a cold breath weapon, and 2. this weapon calls for a Dex save. In the question body you can have as many spoilers as you want in my view (if you are clear about it), but in the question title I would propose being very restrictive.

Comment: @FerventHippo: I'd say it's not really a spoiler that a dragon has a breath weapon associated with its color – and in particular, Tiamat is pretty widely known to be a dragon with multiple heads of different colors as well. I haven't finished the main D&D 5e adventure she appears in, but I already knew that she had a Cold Breath breath weapon, since one of her heads is white. (For comparison: It's not really much more of a spoiler than saying that a powerful wizard can cast high-level spells.)

Comment: ...That said, the body of the question does contain more specific details about her abilities that one might consider a spoiler.

Comment: @V2Blast someone might choose to not prep for a battle against Tiamat with CON save boosts if they know that the ice breath instead calls for a DEX save. I'd call that a spoiler (again a minor one). I'm fine with the body of the question including spoilers.

Comment: @FerventHippo: Fair enough. I was mostly commenting on the idea of "Tiamat has a cold breath weapon" being considered a spoiler.

Answer (score 5):

What exactly would be the spoiler?

Dragons had a dangerous breath since folklore tales were told.

The idea that there are different colors of dragons and they all come with their own alignment and breath weapon was codified for D&D at some point in the early 70s.

Tiamat was first introduced in 1975 in Greyhawk and later in the Monster Manual I in 1977.

The multi-headed dragon form was inspiration for multiple pictures of cover art.

> Spoiler: Tiamats white head breathes ice

is like saying

> Spoiler: it's not a moon, it's a space station

on a Star Wars RPG.

Technically, that is correct. But come on, we don't need to be overprotective. The Titanic will sink. Achilles will take an arrow to the knee (sorry: heel). And white dragon heads breath ice.

Fun fact: I sat in the 2004 movie Troy and next to me was a girl who was seriously mortified that Achilles died after having been hit in the heel by an arrow. I will not add spoiler tags when I talk about someone's Achilles heel, even if it would cost me that moment where I reealized there are actually people out there not even knowing the most basic famous hero stories. We cannot cater to the lowest common denominator.

Comment: It seems to be generally agreed that Tiamat possessing a cold breath weapon is common knowledge, but the fact that it requires a Dex save is a mechanical spoiler in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I think coming up with a detailed spoiler policy for a forum like this will be very difficult and possibly counter-productive.  (I am willing to be proven wrong, but will be swayed by evidence of successful spoiler policies in other stacks rather than theoretical discussions.)

However, I think it's useful to distinguish between two categories:

Specific Content Spoilers:  Here, I am thinking of the details of a particular adventure module, or RPG-related novel, movie, etc, that could only be gained by reading or playing through it.

Lore "Spoilers":  Here, I am thinking of basic accumulated background knowledge, especially background knowledge from basic resources-- rulebooks like the DMG, the Monster Manual(s), or equivalents.  I have a hard time thinking of these as true spoilers.

In this sense, Tiamat having cold breath isn't a spoiler.  The specific details of an encounter with Tiamat in a published module, even something as old as the original Dragonlance modules arguably could be.

There are still probably edge cases here, but this is at least a useful clarification when we talk about this.

Comment: It appears to be common knowledge that Tiamat has a cold breath weapon, but I would call the specific save for that attack a "Specific Content Spoiler" according to your definitions, especially if it is surprising as in this case.

Comment: See how useful the distinction is?  You convinced me!