# Is Back It Up! missing something?

Tags: discussion

Here's Back It Up [as originally suggested for RPGSE by SevenSidedDie](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/627/23970)

> - Something that happened to you **personally**, or
> - Something you can **back up** with a reference.

I feel this is missing something, namely:

> - Something you can **back up** with *careful analysis*.

While personal experience is very important for questions relating to story and 'fun', it doesn't work well with mechanics and statistics-based questions. Just because some specific mechanic did work out well at a table doesn't mean it's not problematic, and only analysis can show that. But folks around here seem to often require Back It Up for all kind of questions.

Many rpg.se regulars have played RPGs for a decade or more, and so have experience with a variety of different systems, rulesets and mechanics, house rules and home brew. But often, that is not enough, and only a 'scientific' look at the rules and mechanics can help. Personal experience is not reproducible and not falsifiable, and therefore I propose this extension to Back It Up.

The famous Good Subjective, Bad Subjective post [2](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) features the xkcd comic about pure and impure science. RPG.se might be an outlier of most StackExchanges that RPGs encompass the full range, from soft/impure story- and experience-only questions over to the other extreme of math/statistics/rule mechanics hard/pure science. Back It Up is applied to all kinds of questions, but it's content currently only applies to soft/impure questions.

With this extension, I hope to build a bridge between the people who prefer soft/impure and those more into hard/pure questions, so that we don't lose out on so many interesting answers just because mods push the soft angle so strongly.

Comment: how would you propose careful analysis of something that is borne out of a social experience, the kind of thing that is often used to help answer questions about problem players for example?

Comment: There's a whole branch of science called psychology that can help with that, as well as lots of economic research into team work and cooperation that shows that analysis is a good approach even for those questions. But this focuses more on questions like the [Harry Potter 5e](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84218/varying-success-when-casting-difficult-spells/84221#84221) one, where the asker clearly wants help with mechanics, but mods still forced Back It Up into the question.

Comment: You may find it helpful to know that SevenSidedDie was quoting [this Stack Exchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) which is [widely used and gets adjusted to each site's experience-based needs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167259/244929).

Comment: You'll get better responses if you ask about a specific situation like the HP 5e question, rather than making it a vaguely all-encompassing "stuff isn't happening the way I think it should" complaint. If the event is symptomatic of a wider problem, say so, but we need to have something actionable to look at.

Comment: @Mala It sounds like your real issue is with subjective guidelines being enforced somewhere inappropriate. Might be better off asking about that in a new question.

Comment: To be fair, it was me--not a mod--who introduced "Back It Up!" into the conversation on that question. The question was quickly accruing close-votes at the time I made my comment that did so, which the mod thought could use the increased visibility of being in-post. Since then the comment's been upvoted four times and the question hasn't gotten any more close votes. I think it's not quite right to assign the mod individual blame in this case.

Comment: @doppelgreener The two things are linked, yes. However, it should be much easier to extent Back It Up than to find strong limits on what definition of subjective should be used.

Comment: @Mala We're unlikely to stop expecting people to back up their experience in answers that demand experience to separate what's viable from what isn't. No amount of analysis is a substitute for experience. Mxyzplk mentioned the scientific method because it's pretty relevant - we analyse possibilities _and then_ make sure they work based on having tried them out for real.

Comment: @nitsua60 I don't want to blame anyone, but me and others have voiced our disappointment with applying soft criteria for hard mechanics questions many times already. I feel my suggestion would allow to build a bridge between the two camps.

Comment: @doppelgreener Exactly, that's what I meant. Your and other's hardline stance would no longer prevent so many interesting answers to mechanics questions, while you could still police soft experience-related questions to your liking.

Comment: @Mala I honestly have no idea what kind of context you're thinking of, but I can tell you "here, use these rules I just made up, I'm sure they'll work, based on never having tried them or anything like them ever" is a very poor quality type of answer we don't really care about collecting more of. If we *have* tried them or something like them, though, suddenly we have experience to assert our mechanical answers will work. And there's plenty of mechanical questions which require no citation of experience aren't GSBS issues, so again, I don't know what you mean really.

Comment: @BESW I know the post, and the xkcd in there shows exactly the problem: rpg.se has questions ranging from both extremes in the spectrum: psychological questions about problem players might be very much to the soft (impure) side of the arrow, while math-, stats- and mechanics-based questions are completely on the right side (hard/pure). Since Back It Up is applied widely to any kind of questions, an extension like that would much improve the 'pure side' of questions asked.

Comment: @Mala Again, if you've got issues with the scope to which Back It Up! is applied, you're probably better off talking about that. Also, if you've got a specific incident in mind, I really suggest you take up BESW's advice and just mention it explicitly and ask about that incident.

Comment: @doppelgreener I can recalculate an analysis of expected outcomes of rules myself, and show that results are false or show unexpected or unwanted outcomes. As soon as 'experience' is applied to hard questions, that's off the table. Someone might have had lots of fun with really bad rules (looking at you, RIFTS)....

Comment: @doppelgreener It's two sides of the same coin, but fixing Back It Up is much, much easier than fixing any kind of generally usable definition of what a subjective question should be on here.

Comment: All the background and context you've been talking about in comments--specific questions, general discontent, support for your thesis, the effect you hope your proposal will have for the site--needs to go into the question or responses to your proposal won't be useful because they don't have the whole picture.

Comment: @BESW I don't want to reopen the rules discussion, just build a bridge between the soft/impure and the hard/pure parts of the xkcd 'sciency' range of questions.

Comment: I am closing this.  It's clear your real question is not about expanding the scope of back it up! in general, but about its applicability in one certain case or class of cases that you are not really bothering to define.  Just waving hands about the generalities will continue with epic argument comment threads and no possible meaningful resolution.  Ask about the problem you have, instead.

Comment: @mxyzplk Please don't close this. I know you are on the soft/impure side, but using your mod powers to stifle discussion and improvements for the hard/pure side is not good for this site. This is a serious suggestion that much would improve answers on this site.

Comment: @mxyzplk 'It's clear your real question is not about expanding the scope of back it up! in general, but about its applicability in one certain case or class of cases that you are not really bothering to define. ' That's your interpretation, and simply not true.

Comment: @Mala: 'blame' was the wrong word to choose in [this comment](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/is-back-it-up-missing-something#comment19229_6382). My only point is that your characterization that ["the mods want to force"](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/is-back-it-up-missing-something#comment19226_6382) some principle on some questions doesn't really seem to apply to [the only question you've mentioned](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/is-back-it-up-missing-something#comment19222_6382). Sorry for introducing that loaded word into things.

Comment: @nitsua60 No worries. And I explicitly stated it _seems_ to me to be that way - because I am well aware my impression is just that - my impression.

Comment: Then clarify it to a real question. The answers here are the only answers to a very vague statement of "hey we should add in analysis." Some kinds of questions do allow for analysis, some don't, and it depends what kind of analysis you're talking about.  This question is too broad and unclear as it stands, as these huge argument threads prove.

Answer (score 14):

Back It Up! applies to subjective questions. It's part of our [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), and the quote in your answer is from there, word for word. Our GSBS guidelines are about questions and answers that are answered from experience and expertise.

If your answer's a subjective answer, you're expected to back it up with experience to differentiate armchair conjecture from actual demonstrated results.

If the question can be answered purely by analysis, it's probably not a subjective question and GSBS and Back It Up! don't apply.

If it needs both analysis and experience, by all means provide analysis, but back up the experience.

Comment: It seems the 'subjective' part is assumed to be everything not answerable by 'rule x on page y', even if the question is for mechanics-only house rule suggestions. Or to say it differently: as long as the current extremely wide definition of subjective is used, an extension to back it up with analysis can only improve the quality of answers.

Comment: -1 *armchair conjecture from actual demonstrated results.* I don't know why you feel like you need to disparage mathematical and statistical analysis of game rules as 'armchair conjecture'. Statistical analysis of game rules is an important tool for many game designers.

Comment: +1 This is my thought exactly: "if the question can be answered purely by analysis, it's probably not a subjective question...."

Comment: @Mala Mathematical and statistical analysis of games rules is, as you say, a useful *tool*. For questions about how well something works *in game*, it is a useful tool but not a sufficient tool. The reason: practical application of theory often reveals things we didn't think about and didn't analyse (or can't analyse, like how something “feels” in play). Hence it's a tool, but not always the correct tool for every question. Sometimes, it's the easy guesswork tool. We want good answers, not guesses.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie But in the same way, experience is also just 'a tool' - only experience is not enough either. That's the basic reason I feel Back It Up should be extended, since at the moment, it only encompasses experience, not analysis, when it should have an entry for both (or neither).

Comment: @Mala No, you can't downgrade *proof by actually doing it successfully* by asserting it's merely a tool.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's twisting my words. Experience alone, without analysis is of the same value as analysis alone, without experience. If you allow one (and current Back It Up does), then you should allow the other, too.

Comment: @Mala They are not of the same value for the purpose of answering subjective questions. Asserting it doesn't make it true.

Comment: @Mala Back It Up doesn't apply to analysis because it's not _relevant_ to analysis. We're not _asking_ you to do Back It Up! on analysis. It's your experience-based issues that need to be backed up, and they need to be backed up by experience. Your analysis can go right there in the answer, _doesn't need_ anything to do with Back It Up.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's, like, totally your opinion, man (to paraphrase a famous movie). ;)

Comment: @doppelgreener It doesn't right now, that's why I propose to extend it.

Comment: @Mala I think we're confusing each other at this point. There's two issues: (a) Analysis is never asked to follow the Back It Up! principle that applies to subjective experience-based matters (which does not include analysis). (b) Subjective experience-based matters are expected to Back It Up!, and analysis doesn't count for that. // To (b) Your initial proposal that subjective experience-based matters can be backed up purely by theoretical analysis is not going to fly, because analysis _isn't sufficient,_ it's why Back It Up! got introduced. To (a) Back It Up! for analysis makes no sense.

Comment: @doppelgreener Then why is a pure mechanics question such as the Harry Potter one mentioned put into the subjective category? Experience is of no value for a purely mechanics-based question such as that one. People decided that one was subjective, so it seems logical that there should be a path within subjective that allows analysis instead of experience.

Comment: @Mala So this _is_ about the Harry Potter thing? You suggested some rules for achieving a result. We have basic expectations people playtest their rules to make sure they work, the same way you probably expect (or ought to expect) people tested out the rules _you're_ using for your gaem to make sure they were any good. If you've got comparable experience, you can cite it to demonstrate what you're doing will work well. People tend to ask for this when it's dubious whether the answer will work. If you've tested it, you know whether it will or won't, after all.

Comment: @doppelgreener 'if you've tested it, you know whether it will or won't, after all.' I disagree with that. A test is just a single sample where you most likely need n=large. An analysis can show fundamental problems that might never even show up with such a small n. Ideally, you have a large sample size as well as an extensive analysis. In the real world, if you allow for n=1 (which seems a given here), answers will only improve if you also allow for a well-written analysis.

Comment: "If your answer's a subjective answer, you're expected to back it up with experience to differentiate armchair conjecture from actual demonstrated results." pretty much nailed it. There's no real way to tell how much thought any given poster has put into an answer, whether or not it's a 10 second brainstorm or a carefully analyzed solution. To combat this, we require experience with said suggestions or references to actual facts (like what a rule says about something).

Comment: But how do you judge experience? If I write an answer and say I played that game with option X under circumstances Y for 10 years and it proved fun, how do you know if I'm making it up or not? Maybe I only played it like that for 1 year? Maybe I just tried it once. Or maybe I only did some theorycrafting and I want to strengthen my argument/answer by some white lies.

Answer (score 6):

It is excluded for a reason.  One man's analysis is another man's random opinion.  Note that the scientific method, for example, is not "analyze, done."   While analysis can be part of formulating a theory or understanding the results of trying out that theory, if it's not tried then it stays a theory.

Analysis can therefore be part of an answer, but an answer based on nothing but is a poor answer.

Comment: One man's experience is no less random than one man's analysis. A scientific proof in a hard-science field does not require real-life usage; a mathematical proof on a paper can be perfectly valid. It's the same with an analysis of specific mechanics. Doesn't need to have x hours table experience at all.

Comment: @Mala Actually, a scientific proof in a hard-science field absolutely requires real-life usage. Why do you think we're still doing super-expensive experiments to prove a proof written in over a hundred years ago (by a super-genius who we keep proving right, Einstein)? Meanwhile, yes, pure math needs only analysis. Roleplaying games, by comparison, are a social science at best, so if even advanced physics needs to be tested outside of a proof on paper, all the more reason RPG analysis needs practical testing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie RPGs are both, therefore, we should be able to use both where appropriate. It seems you want to push for one over the other :(

Comment: @Mala Yes, both where appropriate. Analysis by itself is never appropriate for a subjective question, hence why it has to be supported by experience showing that the analysis is a) correct b) relevant c) complete.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Experience alone is never appropriate for a subjective questions, hence why it has to be supported by analysis showing that the experience is a) reproducible b) relevant c) statistically/mathematically/mechanically sound.

Comment: @Mala You keep making false equivalences to try to overturn the Stack Exchange's tried-and-true policy which was developed out of sweat, blood, and tears to figure out how to make subjective questions answerable within a vote-driven Q&A system, in a way that *actually* floats the best answers to the top. You're not going to overturn 7 years of daily proof just by saying “no no no”.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I did not say 'no no no'. I tried to show you that there is more than _just_ an experience based approach (which you seem to agree with), but you just place your favourite on top. Many mechanics questions with lots of votes and good answers would not be the same if they were posed today instead of earlier when Back It Up wasn't applied so harshly and widely.

Comment: @Mala You keep saying *I* am pushing for something, or that it's *my* favourite. You appear to just not understand that this is SE policy, and it was developed for very good reasons that are still true. That we're better at applying it today is because of growing experience with what works and what doesn't. The simple fact is that your proposal was tried—and it failed. Asking nicely, or yelling at us, or pleading, or accusing us of personal bias, is not going to make an iota of difference to the SE policy. If you don't understand why the policy is in place—try listening and learning.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Back It Up is an rpg.se thing, not a general SE thing. It seems largely influenced by you, given you wrote it up, and is clearly different from Good Subjective/Bad Subjective on it's own. Feel free to insinuate I'm too dumb to listen and learn when I am simply disagreeing with you, but that does not seem productive to a good discussion.

Comment: @Mala OH. Suddenly your objections make much more sense. I didn't write it! It was written by the mods of the first subjective SE (a parenting site), and adopted network-wide by the SE company for all subjective-topic sites. See the two articles I link to in the post of mine you're talking about. Further, you're not dumb—you're just showing a gap in site and SE policy knowledge. My post, which you're talking about, is ridiculous today—we didn't know any better then, but *of course* Good Subjective/Bad Subjective and Back It Up! apply to RPG.se. RPG.se wouldn't work/exist today otherwise.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Indeed, that seems to have been a misunderstanding of mine. Sorry. Still, it does not address my point. When subjective is applied to purely mechanical questions (which I am not even really against), it should not only force one way to answer; for story, sure, but for mechanics, analysis is often way more  valuable than experience. Same as you can write a psychology paper based on an empirical study, but you need to write a mathematical proof for a mathematical paper.

Comment: @Mala Well, part of the problem is that you're assuming BIT and GS/BS are applied to every single question on the site. They're not. They only apply to answers that are being answered with subjective experience. We have *lots* of questions that are about straight mechanics and there isn't a single mention of experience in the answers. Those exist—they're fine. So your question appears to be objecting to something that isn't even happening. BIT doesn't need to be expanded, because it doesn't apply to the kinds of answers you're saying need to be covered by it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's your right to assert that, but that doesn't make it true, unfortunately. If it were that easy, I would have never asked my question in the first place.

Comment: @Mala If you have a specific instance of a question being mishandled, *please* ask about it directly. A question like “Why was this question [link] closed?” would probably work way, way better than what's happening here. Jumping to the assumption that a) it was closed for bad reasons, b) those reasons are caused by bad policy, c) the policy involved is *X*, d) you know how to fix *X*, is a great way to not get a satisfactory response to your meta question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Brighter people as me have tried this already, many times (re: rules-as-written drama), but this clearly didn't solve the problem. By adjusting this, we might be able to build a bridge to at least make it a bit better and improve the quality of answers given. I cannot change the world, but I can try to fix a little piece that is broken - which is what I tried.

Comment: @Mala You can't fix something you don't understand. You're insisting you know how to fix a bedrock part of the site, but in doing so you keep saying things that demonstrate a deep lack of understanding of what you're wanting to change. You already have a good grasp of what you see as the problem, but that is insufficient—you know very well that you need both deep understanding of a problem *and* of the system that it is part of. Ironically, you're failing to do an analysis to understand the system you want to change, before insisting that everyone use your hack.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Again with the attacks. It's not that I don't understand, I simply don't agree with your value judgements.  I tire of being denigrated by you for not agreeing with you.

Comment: @Mala The policy has a long, long history that you seem to be unaware of in general, and in specific you've made a number of outright errors about its nature. I have called that “not understanding” it. I'm sorry if that is insulting, but it appears to be a straightforward fact of this discussion and needs to be said somehow. If you want people to engage fruitfully with your proposals, you will have to go and do some learning about what you want to discuss, at least to the point where you can discuss it somewhat knowledgeably. Declaring feeling insulted is no replacement.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am simply amazed at the certainty with  which you express again and again the disagreeing with you must mean one lacks in either knowledge, comprehension, or both. Wow. That truly leaves no way to a fruitful discussion with you - since meaningful communication requires at least a modicum of respect for another's opinion.

Comment: @Mala You're right that there's no possibility of fruitful discussion. The problem is that you keep thinking that this is a matter of opinion, and that your “opponents”are ideologically motivated. We're not. You're lacking basic grounding in the subject you want to discuss. You've also failed to actually describe the problem your change is supposed to fix. Both are automatic grounds for rejection in every science, as you well know. Please, **I urge you to ask a question about your *problem* instead of asking everyone to accept your solution on faith**.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Really, your assertions about my oh so many deficiencies are not productive. No, I don't think the things you accuse me of with regards to opinion and ideology. I am not sure why you need to turn discussion partners into opponents. No, I'm not lacking basic grounding in the subject. No matter how much you repeat your attacks, it doesn't make them true. Please desist from attacking me in further comments if you don't have any actual, factual contributions to bring to the discussion. It's unseemly that you as a mod treat people this way.

Comment: Not to be petty or anything, but you two should have taken this to chat (or a bar with a few beers) long ago.