# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/domain-name-suggestions).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your [logo](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/site-logo-design))

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: I don't know - many of those taglines Robert cites are IMO actually fairly poor and only useful when already attached to a strong brand.  We don't have a strong brand, thus IMO our motto, like "king of beers," should have some indication what the heck this is about.

Comment: @mxyzplk It's less about the motto/tagline being a useful stand-in for our brand, as it is *building* a brand (i.e., a consistent presentation) for our front page. When someone lands on the front page, they should very quickly know what we're about, both in terms of function and feel.

Comment: I hate being that guy, but shouldn't this be CW?

Comment: @LeguRi: You are correct. Done.

Comment: Should this have the [featured] tag?

Comment: Since we're looking for three things—elevator pitches, taglines, and mottos, I tried to categorise the suggestions. If I got the intent wrong, please correct them!

Answer (score 9):

Ask the Table

(motto)

Comment: +1, but I'd like to suggest a revision (stealing a few things from above):
AskTheTable: We accept your quest!
Level up your RPG skills with expert Q&A.

Comment: Done! I thought I should ask before changing your suggestion

Comment: I think we can combine suggestions we like eventually. The suggestions I've made so far all feel like just a setup for another few words of branding. ("Stack the dice in your favour — Level up your roleplaying via Q&A with experts!" kind of thing.) If the bits are separate we can vote on them individually.

Comment: Actually, can we split this more? We're looking for three things: elevator pitches, taglines, and mottos. I like "ask the table" as a motto or short tagline, but I'm cool-ish on the quest part.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: good suggestion. done.

Answer (score 6):

Level up your RPG gaming skills with expert Q&A!

(elevator pitch)

Comment: This draws on both Pat's and yhw's answers, to ideally combine "less jargoney" with "more descriptive".

Comment: It just doesn't feel smooth to me, but I don't know how I would fix it.  The via seems out of place ...

Comment: I agree - I hate my suggestions as much as all these others.

Comment: Suggest changing to "Level up your RPG skills with expert Q&A" to make it smoother

Comment: Good idea, done!

Answer (score 6):

The internet equivalent of a shining tower full of wizened sages and interstellar rules-lawyer robots. And we're here to help.

(elevator pitch)

Answer (score 5):

Master your game.

(tagline)

Answer (score 5):

Because sometimes rulebooks won't have the answers.

**variation:** Because sometimes rulebooks won't have the answers, and sometimes you won't even have the rulebooks.

(Tagline/elevator pitch)

Comment: I like this one up until the comma, the second clause isn't needed IMHO.

Comment: @Pat Ludwig - I had been flirting with the same thought; edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Where helpful game experts hang out. The biggest adventuring party ever.

(elevator pitch)

Answer (score 3):

Stack the dice in your favour.

(Tagline. Superfluous U optional of course.)

Comment: +1 for using "stack"

Comment: +1 for the same reason... but we need to be careful not to associate _too_ strongly with StackExchange as it has an identity which is kind of bound to programming (I've never been able to describe StackExchnage without going back to StackOverflow) and we're not about programming...

Comment: -1; even though it made me smile when I saw it, the name makes me think of cheating/munchkining (like GiantInThePlayground)

Comment: @RMorrisey Fair comment. :) It's hard to come up with something pithy that says "Give yourself an advantage!" without also implying "Give your *character* an unfair advantage!" This just might not fit the bill.

Answer (score 3):

Ask The GM: The RPG player's definitive Q&A resource.

Comment: +1, but FYI I like the second half, and not the first.

Answer (score 3):

Tagline: It's like a Tome of Infinite Wisdom, but with tags

Answer (score 3):

Questing for Answers

( Motto )

Answer (score 2):

Level Up!

(Motto)

Answer (score 2):

Improve your table-top experience!

(Tagline)

Comment: Can you make that a separate answer so it can be voted on?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: done.

Answer (score 2):

Great Q&A: Quest and Answers

Comment: Maybe better: "Heroic Q&A"?

Answer (score 2):

Sage Advice for every role-playing game.

(Tagline)

Comment: very similar to the [SeasonedAdvice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Answer (score 1):

Get in character with focused help on your favorite tabletop RPGs!

(elevator pitch)

Answer (score 1):

Crit your knowledge checks.

(tagline)

Answer (score 1):

Gain table-top XP!

Answer (score 1):

We accept you Quest(ion)!

(tagline)

Answer (score 1):

Quests and Answers: What you're seeking is here.

(tagline?)

Answer (score 1):

Elevator Pitch: Everything you always wanted to know about RPGs but didn't know where to ask

Answer (score 1):

Motto: We're all about RPGs. Any questions?

Answer (score 1):

The next time you get plane-shifted during a grapple, we'll be here to help.

(Elevator pitch)

Answer (score 0):

RPG Knowledge Check.

(motto+2)